# Want to bring inheritance Money from Pakistan to UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, international-transfer, inheritance, pakistan

What are the taxes? or other Uk Gov-related rules that we need to keep in mind in order to bring inherited money from Pakistan to the UK? My Grandfather passed away and left an inheritance for his kids (my father), My grandfather never lived in Uk and was domiciled in Pakistan but my father lives in the UK and wants to bring the Money here to the UK. I have asked HMRC and they said that the UK government doesn't care and my father does not have to pay inheritance tax on this as it is not from the UK. Can someone please explain the procedure to transfer the money to the UK? and if there is any tax or any charge that we need to pay?

Kind Regards

Comment: There is no "official" way to send money. There are companies that send money, like Western Union (old) and Transferwise (new) and also your bank. You should ask them for advice, moving money is their job. You can shop around for the best fee, but don't fall for any scams. (The ones I listed are trustworthy)

Comment: The tax and the sending should be completely separate problems.

Comment: Of course, before transfering the money, all the proper paperwork needs to be filled at Pakistan.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers but my question is about Tax and any rules around foreign inheritance that we are bringing to the UK. The money transfer is not much of an issue provided we have proof or legitimate money. Just want to know the rules and regulations around bringing foreign inheritance to the UK.

Comment: @xack There’s no tax or other government charge to pay. The banks doing the transfer will probably charge you something, so you should shop around to look for the best deal.

Comment: Are you only interested in the UK side, or also in what is allowed with moving the money out of Pakistan?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I would also like to know the ruled around moving money out of Pakistan?

Comment: I was wondering if you managed to managed to bring your inheritance to the uk as I am in the same situation where I have sold some land and want to know the process of bringing the money to the uk ( how much does the bank allow you to send to Uk) at a time and if there is any other ways anyone can recommend

Answer (score 3):

For the UK side, there is no tax or official charge payable to transfer the money in.

As HMRC have already told you, there's no inheritance tax applicable as the deceased wasn't UK based.

For a transfer, the source of the money is irrelevant as long as it is legal and you can demonstrate that if asked for money laundering purposes.

You will need to use some service to actually send the money and exchange it into sterling. Either a bank or a newer service focused specifically on foreign transfers, like Transferwise should be able to help with that. Those services don't come for free and you should carefully check both the fees they explicitly charge and how competitive the exchange rate they offer is.